# _version_ field must exist in schema and be searchable : Solr 6.2.0

Tags: solr

I am facing a similar issue to [the questions asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942477/solr-version-field-must-exist-in-schema-and-be-searchable). However, I am not able to resolve the error even after restarting the solr server.

As mentioned in the referenced question, I have checked everything.

1. Schema version is 1.6
2. No *types* or *fields* tags present.

Here is my `schema.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>    
<schema name="test" version="1.6">    
  <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

  <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
  <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

  <!-- Field type demonstrating an Analyzer failure -->
  <fieldType name="failtype1" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0"
              catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

  <!-- Demonstrating ignoreCaseChange -->
  <fieldType name="wdf_nocase" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0"
              catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

  <fieldType name="wdf_preserve" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0"
              catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>


  <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true"/>

  <!-- format for date is 1995-12-31T23:59:59.999Z and only the fractional
       seconds part (.999) is optional.
    -->
  <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0"/>
  <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="6"/>


  <!-- solr.TextField allows the specification of custom
       text analyzers specified as a tokenizer and a list
       of token filters.
    -->
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>


  <fieldType name="nametext" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.WhitespaceAnalyzer"/>
  </fieldType>

  <fieldType name="teststop" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

  <!-- fieldTypes in this section isolate tokenizers and tokenfilters for testing -->
  <fieldType name="lowertok" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="keywordtok" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory" pattern="keyword"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="standardtok" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="lettertok" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.LetterTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="whitetok" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="HTMLstandardtok" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="HTMLwhitetok" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="standardtokfilt" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="standardfilt" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="lowerfilt" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="lowerpunctfilt" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1"
              catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="patternreplacefilt" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory" pattern="keyword"/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
              pattern="([^a-zA-Z])" replacement="_" replace="all"
      />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory" pattern="keyword"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="patterntok" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=","/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="porterfilt" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <!-- fieldType name="snowballfilt" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType -->
  <fieldType name="engporterfilt" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="custengporterfilt" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="stopfilt" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="custstopfilt" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="lengthfilt" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="5"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="charfilthtmlmap" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

  <fieldType name="subword" class="solr.TextField" multiValued="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1"
              catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0"
              catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

  <fieldType name="numericsubword" class="solr.TextField" multiValued="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnNumerics="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" generateWordParts="1"
              generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnNumerics="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" generateWordParts="1"
              generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

  <fieldType name="protectedsubword" class="solr.TextField" multiValued="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnNumerics="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" generateWordParts="1"
              generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>


  <!-- more flexible in matching skus, but more chance of a false match -->
  <fieldType name="skutype1" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1"
              catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1"
              catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

  <!-- less flexible in matching skus, but less chance of a false match -->
  <fieldType name="skutype2" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1"
              catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1"
              catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

  <!-- less flexible in matching skus, but less chance of a false match -->
  <fieldType name="syn" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>


  <fieldType name="unstored" class="solr.StrField" indexed="true" stored="false"/>


  <fieldType name="textgap" class="solr.TextField" multiValued="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

  <fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField"/>

  <!-- Try out some point types -->
  <fieldType name="xy" class="solr.PointType" dimension="2" subFieldType="double"/>
  <fieldType name="x" class="solr.PointType" dimension="1" subFieldType="double"/>
  <fieldType name="tenD" class="solr.PointType" dimension="10" subFieldType="double"/>
  <!-- Use the sub field suffix -->
  <fieldType name="xyd" class="solr.PointType" dimension="2" subFieldSuffix="_d1"/>
  <fieldType name="geohash" class="solr.GeoHashField"/>


  <fieldType name="latLon" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldType="double"/>

  <!--  some per-field similarity examples -->

  <!--  specify a Similarity classname directly -->
  <!--
  <fieldType name="sim1" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <similarity class="org.apache.lucene.misc.SweetSpotSimilarity"/>
  </fieldType>
  -->
  <!--  specify a Similarity factory -->
  <!--
  <fieldType name="sim2" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <similarity class="org.apache.solr.search.similarities.CustomSimilarityFactory">
      <str name="echo">is there an echo?</str>
    </similarity>
  </fieldType>
  -->
  <!-- don't specify any sim at all: get the default  -->
  <!--
  <fieldType name="sim3" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.MockTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  -->


  <field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="false"/>
  <field name="signatureField" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="uuid" type="uuid" stored="true"/>
  <field name="name" type="nametext" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="subject" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="title" type="nametext" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="weight" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <field name="bday" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

  <field name="title_stemmed" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="title_lettertok" type="lettertok" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

  <field name="syn" type="syn" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <!-- to test property inheritance and overriding -->
  <field name="shouldbeunstored" type="unstored"/>
  <field name="shouldbestored" type="unstored" stored="true"/>
  <field name="shouldbeunindexed" type="unstored" indexed="false" stored="true"/>

  <!-- Test points -->
  <!-- Test points -->
  <field name="home" type="xy" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <field name="x" type="x" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <field name="homed" type="xyd" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <field name="home_ns" type="xy" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false"/>
  <field name="work" type="xy" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

  <field name="home_ll" type="latLon" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <field name="home_gh" type="geohash" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>


  <field name="point10" type="tenD" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>


  <!-- test different combinations of indexed and stored -->
  <field name="bind" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="bsto" type="boolean" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
  <field name="bindsto" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="isto" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
  <field name="iind" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="ssto" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
  <field name="sind" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="sindsto" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <!-- test combinations of term vector settings -->
  <field name="test_basictv" type="text" termVectors="true"/>
  <field name="test_notv" type="text" termVectors="false"/>
  <field name="test_postv" type="text" termVectors="true" termPositions="true"/>
  <field name="test_offtv" type="text" termVectors="true" termOffsets="true"/>
  <field name="test_posofftv" type="text" termVectors="true"
         termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>

  <!-- fields to test individual tokenizers and tokenfilters -->
  <field name="teststop" type="teststop" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="lowertok" type="lowertok" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="keywordtok" type="keywordtok" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="standardtok" type="standardtok" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="HTMLstandardtok" type="HTMLstandardtok" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="lettertok" type="lettertok" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="whitetok" type="whitetok" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="HTMLwhitetok" type="HTMLwhitetok" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="standardtokfilt" type="standardtokfilt" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="standardfilt" type="standardfilt" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="lowerfilt" type="lowerfilt" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="lowerfilt1" type="lowerfilt" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="lowerfilt1and2" type="lowerfilt" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="patterntok" type="patterntok" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="patternreplacefilt" type="patternreplacefilt" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="porterfilt" type="porterfilt" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="engporterfilt" type="engporterfilt" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="custengporterfilt" type="custengporterfilt" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="stopfilt" type="stopfilt" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="custstopfilt" type="custstopfilt" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="lengthfilt" type="lengthfilt" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="wdf_nocase" type="wdf_nocase" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="wdf_preserve" type="wdf_preserve" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <field name="numberpartfail" type="failtype1" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <field name="nullfirst" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" sortMissingFirst="true" multiValued="false"/>

  <field name="subword" type="subword" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="subword_offsets" type="subword" indexed="true" stored="true" termOffsets="true"/>
  <field name="numericsubword" type="numericsubword" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="protectedsubword" type="protectedsubword" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <field name="sku1" type="skutype1" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="sku2" type="skutype2" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <field name="textgap" type="textgap" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" multiValued="false"/>
  <field name="multiDefault" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" default="muLti-Default" multiValued="true"/>
  <field name="intDefault" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" default="42" multiValued="false"/>

  <!--
  <field name="sim1text" type="sim1" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="sim2text" type="sim2" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="sim3text" type="sim3" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  -->

  <field name="tlong" type="tlong" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <!-- Dynamic field definitions.  If a field name is not found, dynamicFields
       will be used if the name matches any of the patterns.
       RESTRICTION: the glob-like pattern in the name attribute must have
       a "*" only at the start or the end.
       EXAMPLE:  name="*_i" will match any field ending in _i (like myid_i, z_i)
       Longer patterns will be matched first.  if equal size patterns
       both match, the first appearing in the schema will be used.
  -->
  <dynamicField name="*_i" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_i1" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

  <dynamicField name="*_s" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_s1" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_l" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_l1" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_t" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_b" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_f" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_f1" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_d" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_d1" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_dt1" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

  <!-- some trie-coded dynamic fields for faster range queries -->
  <dynamicField name="*_ti" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_ti1" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_tl" type="tlong" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_tl1" type="tlong" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_tf" type="tfloat" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_tf1" type="tfloat" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_td" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_td1" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_tds" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_tdt" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_tdt1" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

  <dynamicField name="*_sI" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_sS" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="t_*" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="tv_*" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"
                termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="tv_mv_*" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"
                termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>

  <dynamicField name="*_p" type="xyd" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

  <!-- special fields for dynamic copyField test -->
  <dynamicField name="dynamic_*" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_dynamic" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <!-- for testing to ensure that longer patterns are matched first -->
  <dynamicField name="*aa" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*aaa" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true"/>

  <!-- ignored becuase not stored or indexed -->
  <dynamicField name="*_ignored" type="text" indexed="false" stored="false"/>

  <dynamicField name="*_mfacet" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

  <!-- make sure custom sims work with dynamic fields -->
  <!--
  <dynamicField name="*_sim1" type="sim1" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_sim2" type="sim2" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <dynamicField name="*_sim3" type="sim3" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  -->

  <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

  <!-- copyField commands copy one field to another at the time a document
        is added to the index.  It's used either to index the same field different
        ways, or to add multiple fields to the same field for easier/faster searching.
   -->
  <copyField source="title" dest="title_stemmed"/>
  <copyField source="title" dest="title_lettertok"/>

  <copyField source="title" dest="text"/>
  <copyField source="subject" dest="text"/>

  <copyField source="lowerfilt1" dest="lowerfilt1and2"/>
  <copyField source="lowerfilt" dest="lowerfilt1and2"/>

  <copyField source="*_t" dest="text"/>

  <copyField source="id" dest="range_facet_l"/>
  <copyField source="range_facet_f" dest="range_facet_d"/>

  <!-- dynamic destination -->
  <copyField source="*_dynamic" dest="dynamic_*"/>

</schema>
```

Not sure why is it still giving issues. Attaching a screenshot for reference:
[image: solr 6.2.0 _version_ error]

If it makes a difference, I got the schema.xml file from https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/solrj/src/test-files/solrj/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml

Answer (score 1):

you need to have a field definition like:

```
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

and make sure that you update the schema.xml file in Zookeeper using the zkcli before restarting all the nodes.